# how to know whether check box is checked or not

Tags: jquery

```
$('[name="SelectHighlights"]:checked').each(function () {
        var row = $(this).closest('tr');


        var high = {
            AccountId: row.find('td:nth-child(3)').text(),
            Highcomments: row.find('td:nth-child(4)> input').val()
        };
        HighlightsArea.push(high);

    });
```

this is my code for retreiving the rows with checkbox checked

how to retreive the rows where check box is not checked

Please help me 
Thanks in advance

Comment: 10 seconds on Google would [**show you that it's really quite easy**](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

Comment: @Bojangles Your link doesn't answer the question. "how to retreive the rows where check box is NOT checked" (emphasis mine).

Comment: That's a simple loop and some extra logic. The main question here is how to filter checkboxes that _are_ checked

Answer (score 2):

Use :not() selector

```
$('[name="SelectHighlights"]:not(:checked)').each(function () {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');


    var high = {
        AccountId: row.find('td:nth-child(3)').text(),
        Highcomments: row.find('td:nth-child(4)> input').val()
    };
    HighlightsArea.push(high);
 });
```

Comment: Using this code i am able to get the unchecked rows but i am getting every record twice in the array

Answer (score 1):

As you are already getting the checked boxes in a loop, I'd use the same loop for all checkboxes, and check inside the loop if they are checked or not, instead of adding another loop for unchecked boxes.

```
$('[name="SelectHighlights"]').each(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        // do this if this checkbox is checked
    }else{
        // do this is this checkbox is not checked
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][name="SelectHighlights"]:checked').each(function () {
       var row = $(this).closest('tr');
```

or directly

```
$('input[name="SelectHighlights"]:checked').each(function () {
       var row = $(this).closest('tr');
```

As per your edited question you can get both of the checkboxes like

```
$('input[name="SelectHighlights"]').each(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('checked')){
         //Do your stuff with checked 
    }else{
         // Do your stuff with unchecked 
    }
});
```

Comment: Instead of checking all the checkboxes just consider all the checked ones